# Python: Adding XML Payload to Requests POST Isn't Working

Tags: python, xml, rest, api, python-requests

I am submitting media processing jobs to a media transcode API.

It is REST based and accepts a few values in the call:

- **workflowIdentifier** (required): unique ID to the API, this is static
- **sourceFilename** (required): url encoded samba UNC path
- **jobName** (optional): string
- **context** (optional): This is an XML payload read by the API

Here is what an example manual submit would look like (with much of the XML truncated for readability)

```
POST http://1.1.1.1:1234/SubmitRest/SubmitFile?workflowIdentifier=4r5t6y7u&sourceFilename=%5C%5C10.10.1.20%5Cteststore%5Cmedia%5CTEST001E1.mov&jobName=mytestjob&context=%3CContext+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2FTelestream.Vantage.Sdk%2F2010%2F07%22+xmlns%3Ai%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchem...
```

**When the XML (for context) is small enough THIS WORKS**

However in our production environment it's a VERY large XML payload to be sent to "context" so I'm getting:

```
<hr><p>HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.</p>
```

-
So after doing a bit of searching, I've tried the following

```
context_string = (the very large XML document as a string)
source_file =
    '%5C%5C10.10.1.20%5Cteststore%5Cmedia%5CTEST001E1.mov'
job_name = 'testjob'
workflow_id = '4r5t6y7u'
url = 'http://1.1.1.1:1234/SubmitRest/SubmitFile?workflowIdentifier=' + workflow_id + '&sourceFilename=' + source_file + '&jobName=' + job_name
reply = requests.post(url, data={'context': context_string})
```

**The job is successfully accepted by the API, BUT the context payload is ignored.**

(Please note that I've tried with the XML url encoded, and as a normal string )

I also tried it like this:

```
context_string = (the very large XML document as a string)
source_file =
        '%5C%5C10.10.1.20%5Cteststore%5Cmedia%5CTEST001E1.mov'
job_name = 'testjob'
workflow_id = '4r5t6y7u'
payload = {'workflowIdentifier': workflow_id, 'sourceFilename': source_file, 'context': context_stringa, 'jobName': jobname}
reply = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

This doesn't work at all, it fails since the required fields are not found (such as workflowIdentifier

Totally stumped on why it is working when I can fit all the data into the one URI, but it doesn't work when I try and add it to a payload with requests(data=)

So my main question is -- how can I submit this via python requests just like if it was all part of the URI POST call? I must be doing something wrong here.

**EDIT:**

So I did a **packet capture** on the POST call:
Here is the command I sent:

```
requests.post(url, data={'context': context_string})
```

Here is what it looks like on the packet capture:

```
POST /SubmitRest/SubmitFile?workflowIdentifier=4r5t6y7u&sourceFilename=%5C%5C10.10.1.20%5Cteststore%5Cmedia%5CTEST001E1.mov&jobName=testjob HTTP/1.1
Host: x.x.x.x:1234
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.11.1
Content-Length: 20749

context=<Context xmlns="http://Telestream.Vantage.Sdk/2010/07" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><xmlns i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Telestream.Soa.Vocabulary" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml.Serialization"/>
(omitted the rest of the XML)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem has nothing to do with Python. The old Vantage APIs required context.xml to be put as a part of the URL. If your URL becomes too long, it fails. You can confirm the same by testing through Postman (Without Python, I meant.)

I would recommend updating to the latest Vantage (8.0), and its API version (5+). The newer API accepts JSON payloads. All variables and their values goes as a part of the JSON without impacting the URL.

The documentation to the new API is available as a part of the Vantage SDK. Posting the [URL](http://dynamic.telestream.net/downloads/download-sdk.asp?prodid=sdk&_ga=2.56358958.46177744.1587808287-1850024215.1580125280), you will have to create an account to access it.

I have tried the same using Postman, and it works. You can try the same.